# phantomjs and run-jasmine.js timeouts

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, phantomjs

So I've got an odd issue.

I've got a Jasmine test runner running locally on my machine available at localhost:8080/test/runner.html

When I open it in a web browser it works perfectly.

I wanted to automate this so I'm using phantomjs (installed from brew -- I'm on a mac) and I'm using the example run-jasmine.js file from the code.

But, whenever I run it against the URL, I get this:

```
phantomjs war/test/spec/run_jasmine.js http://localhost:8080/test/runner.html
'waitFor()' timeout
```

So I wrote a really simple script to see if there is something I'm missing:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.open(phantom.args[0],
function(status) {
    if (status !== "success") {
        console.log("Unable to access network");
        phantom.exit();
    } else {
        if (document.body.querySelector('#hello')) {
            console.log('hi');
        }
    }
});
```

And created a new HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>hi</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="hi"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the thing still just hangs forever.

Am I missing something here?  I know the page is being loaded, but it doesn't look like phantomjs is ever parsing it.

Comment: This may sound silly, but if you replace localhost with 127.0.0.1 ? Any difference?

Comment: That is not silly, but sadly doesn't work.  But got me to thinking -- what happens if I try to telnet to port 8080 and just do a `GET /test/runner.html HTTP/1.1`. Low and behold - `HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Connection: close
Server: Jetty(6.1.x)`  So like, a problem with the server... (it's GAE's local server)

Comment: Oh f a duck.  The server is throwing up a page requesting login credentials.  I have to code that into this now.  And deal with cookies.  Or just move to a different subdirectory...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well I feel dumb.

The /test/ requires authentication.

Comment: haha, I made exactly the same mistake when implementing phantomjs with our .net solution. That's how we learn!

Comment: plus one for feeling dumb :)